# Quando e de que forma devemos utilizar as conjunções adversativas "mas", "contudo", "porém", "no entanto", "entretanto" e "todavia"?

Tags: gramática, conjunções

As conjunções adversativas `mas`, `contudo`, `porém`, `no entanto`, `entretanto` e `todavia` são utilizadas no sentido de oposição, restrição ou compensação.

> Exemplos:
>   Tentei explicar, mas não sei se que consegui ser claro.
>   Nesta pergunta todas estas conjunções tem o mesmo sentido, no entanto pode existir regras para melhor utiliza-las.

Existe alguma regra para se escolher entre uma ou outra?

Quando e de que forma devemos utilizar estas conjunções?

Comment: Acho que não existe nenhuma regra e podes usar todas, uma vez que, são sinónimos.

Comment: @JorgeB. em Portugal **sinônimos** é com acento agudo? **sinónimos**

Comment: É sim @LucasMotta **sinónimos**.

Comment: Legal, eu também não sabia .

Comment: foi realmente no entanto não há explicação a respeito da adversativa TODAVIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As conjunções adversativas ligam duas orações ou palavras, expressando
>   ideia de contraste ou compensação. Também pode gerar um sentido de
>   consequência a algo dito anteriormente (ex.: mas, porém, todavia,
>   entretanto, mesmo assim, no entanto, senão, não obstante, contudo,
>   etc).
>
> **Obs.:** Antes das Conjunções adversativas a vírgula é obrigatória

---

**REGRAS**

> Das conjunções adversativas, "mas" deve ser empregada sempre no
>   início da oração: as outras (porém, todavia, contudo, entretanto, no
>   entanto, etc.) podem vir no início ou no meio.

**Exemplos:**

- *Ninguém respondeu à pergunta, **mas** os alunos sabiam a resposta.*
- *Ninguém respondeu à pergunta; os alunos, **porém**, sabiam a resposta.*

---

> A palavra "pois", quando é conjunção conclusiva, vem geralmente após
>   um ou mais termos da oração a que pertence.

**Exemplo:**

- *Você o provocou com essas palavras; `não se queixe`, **pois**, de seus ataques.*

---

> Quando é conjunção explicativa," pois" vem, geralmente, após um verbo
>   no imperativo e sempre no início da oração a que pertence.

**Exemplo:**

- *Não `tenha` receio, **pois** eu a protegerei...*

---

**Mais Exemplos:**

- *Tentei chegar na hora, **porém** me atrasei.*
- *Ela trabalha muito, **mas** ganha pouco.*
- *Não ganhei o prêmio, **no entanto** dei o melhor de mim.*
- *Não vi meu sobrinho crescer, **no entanto** está um homem.*